# django rest framework social auth oauth2

Tags: angular, rest, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-socialauth

I' m working on django rest framework (django 2) for the backend with angular 5 for the client. I'm using [*this*](https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2/issues/113) module for `social auth`.

I have some important questions about it and my code below.

From documentation we must send `client_id`, `secret_id` and client secret and user and password to this URL `http://localhost:8000/auth/token` and in return, it will give us the access_token. So we should have secret_id and client_id in client side... is it safe to keep this data there? If not, what is the correct way?

```
  private client_id = "uvsNRS7segoeAY71kLlqxotWx8iUhK2DoRi4ru84";
  private client_secret= "NXpXO1RzfQIHRImDu5LoM2W7ln3VACT6fWSSKQhhAXdBgec8yRTXIC1AlFzMbBiPDBx5e9SaBztf9tSINoJxRpybZXHAtuwYOtDySyJWOmeTkC22JMv64IUr2PUyEjwU";

  onSubmit({value, valid}) {
    if (!valid) {
      console.log("form in invalid!");
    }
    let username = value.username;
    let password = value.password;

    this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8000/auth/token/", {client_id: this.client_id,client_secret: this.client_secret,grant_type: "password",username : username, password: password})
      .subscribe(
        user => {
          console.log(user)
          if (user && user.access_token) {
            console.log(user)
            localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(user.access_token));

            this.dialogRef.close(username);
            this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
          }
        }, err => {
          this.error = err.error.non_field_errors;
        }
      );
  }
```

1. this module provide us "access_token". Is there any way to use `jwt` instead of this?
2. Is there any module that support `jwt` for django 2 `social auth`? By default I searched many times for it but all packages are for django 1.1.
   If you know something better please tell me.
3. In client side: what is the best way to find what is user role to grant him access to review the routes?

Comment: Enlighten us a bit with text and ref how you tried to your questions solved. It improves the question and motivates other to help you faster.

Comment: i tried to improve my question . thanks

Comment: Well done. I can see you did your best. as you can see I've made some edits to improve the question even more ;-) Hope it gets answered for you soon. GL.